# Upload file without activeform in yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii2

I have a form (not activeform) that submits a text input and a file input. I can save the text field but the file is not detected.

**View:**

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>bicycle_no</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="bicycle_no" placeholder="" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>image</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="file" type="file">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <a href="<?=Yii::$app->homeUrl?>/site/index" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I can get the image in controller:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
  //var_dump($_FILES['file']; // <<-- shows image data
  $model['image_uploaded'] = $this->upload();
}

public function upload(){

    $model = new UploadImage();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

    $path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/upload/couriers/images/';
    //return $path;

    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
    echo json_encode($model->file); # <<--- shoes nothing
        $model->path = $path;
        if($model->upload()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return $model->getErrors();
        }
}
```

And the error i get is as follows:

```
Please upload a file!
```

Any help would be most welcomed!

Comment: Check model loaded with post data?

Comment: No the post data is not loaded into $model

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to change 2 things:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

to:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '');
```

AND

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
```

to:

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
```

It's because youre not using your model in form. Method `load()` gets 2 parameters, first is `$data` - which you already know, and second is `$formName`. Default is set to `null`, but if it's `null`, it will prepare form name from your model, for example `YourModel[data_key]`. In your case, youre not using `ActiveForm` and model to generate form, so you don't have form name in your html. By setting this to `''` youre telling `ActiveRecord` to load data without form.

Comment: OMG, It WORKED!!! Thank you Yupik. I wouldn't come up with such a solution. So what is `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '');` really?

Comment: Thanks! You're life saver!